# How to remove the last comma and space from string (if there) using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in a C# application and was wondering what would be the correct way to check if the last two characters are `,` (comma and space) and remove them using a regex if so.

Comment: in case if you insist on regex solution - `string output = Regex.Replace("my string, ", ", $", "");`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov - Thank you. I went with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry I was late the the party.)

*Yes*, this is *not* something for which you have to or should use a regex; *but since you asked* how to do it with a regex (e.g. maybe you are just curious, and "suppose I have to to this with a regex" hypotheticals are a good way to learn), consider the following pattern:

```
(.*?)(, )?$
```

You can test it in a [related regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/d05qn6).

Key points:

- `(.*?)` – Match zero or more (`*`) of any character except newline (`.`) *as few times as possible* (`?`).
- `(, )?$` – Match zero or one (`?`) `,` *at the end* (`$`).

Also, the following C# example with this pattern...

```
var str1 = "whatever, ";
var str2 = "whatever, ,";
var str3 = "";

var regex = new Regex("(.*?)(, )?$");
var str1Match = regex.Match(str1);
var str2Match = regex.Match(str2);
var str3Match = regex.Match(str3);

Console.WriteLine(str1Match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(str2Match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(str3Match.Groups[1].Value);
```

...produces the following outputs:

- `str1` (`"whatever, "`) *=>* `whatever`
- `str2` (`"whatever, ,"`) *=>* `whatever, ,`
- `str3` (`""`) *=>*

It uses `Groups[1].Value` to get the first capture group's value (i.e. the value matched by `(.*?)` rather than `(, )?` (if any)).

**Edit:**

I actually like what @UlugbekUmirov suggested in his comment (`string output = Regex.Replace("my string, ", ", $", "");`) even better because it is super simple; but hopefully you find the approach I outlined instructive.

Comment: Thank you for solving with `regex` and providing great detail. I marked you as the answer even though I changed it up a bit to cut down on the amount of lines but pretty much went with @UlugbekUmirov solution.

Comment: @scapegoat17: You're welcome. Yes, shortening it is in order if you are not seeking to break out every step for instructive clarity. I think you mistyped, though: `Regex.Match(r,"(.*?)(, )?$)").ToString();` yields an `ArgumentException` with the message *parsing "(.\*?)(, )?$)" - Too many )'s.*  I think what you may've been looking for then is `Regex.Match(r,"(.*?)(, )?$").Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: That is correct, found that out after submitting and just went ahead and removed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

A working solution without regex :

```
string str = "dfsf, ";

if (str.EndsWith(", "))
    str = str.Remove(str.Length - 2);
```

We remove 2 because 2 is the length of `", "`.

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7RCNeM)

Answer (score 10):

You don't need Regex for that, use [`String.TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
string updatedString = yourString.TrimEnd(',', ' ');
```

You can also specify a string and call `ToCharArray` like:

```
string str = "something,  ,   ,,,,   ";
string updatedString = str.TrimEnd(", ".ToCharArray());
```

would give you `"something"`

If you only want to remove **a single occurrence** of `", "` *(comma and space at the end)* then use:

```
if (str.EndsWith(", "))
    updatedString = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 2);
```

Comment: This would also remove multiple trailing commas/spaces, which might be desirable, but doesn't match the OP's stated requirement of only checking the last two characters.

Comment: @DanBryant, added a solution for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than removing the trailing comma and space it's easier to simply generate the string without an extra comma in the first place.  When generating the comma separated values simply use `String.Join` to join all of the strings together with a particular separator:

```
var line = string.Join(", ", yourCollectionOfValues);
```

It'll be easier and faster than appending the values together, and `Join` will already handle ensure that there is no trailing separator.

Comment: @probrandono Try it and see.

Comment: Great! Aggregate would be replaced by this in most of the cases! Thanks.